# Banno API - Which User Ability sets Member Transfers to False?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am attempting to disable the six Permissions on the Banno Backend User Overview page. I have been able to disable all of them except for Member Transfers via the User Abilities PUT API call:

- https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/abilities/details/#/User%20Specific%20Abilities/put_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users__userId__abilities_update

I've tried the below abilities but none of them have disabled the Member Transfers ability/permission. Can someone please let me know which of the abilities/permissions controls Member Transfers?

- "ask_question_on_aggregation_transfer": false
- "schedulable_transfers": false
- "alternate_account_transfer_flow": false
- "member_to_member_transfers": false
- "disable_transfers_for_cash_management_users": false
- "account_to_account": false

[image: Banno Backend Overview Permissions]

Comment: I was informed today by our digital team that we have a Episys PowerOn that is being used to provide the functionality of Member to Member Transfers within Banno. Could that potentially be the reason the API is not disabling the Member Transfers ability/permission? Regardless, I would still like confirmation of which Ability should disable Member Transfers for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right right that `member_to_member_transfers` is the correct ability to target. However, it is not currently supported through the API.

The PUT `/a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/abilities/update` endpoint will exclusively accept the abilities that are currently [documented](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/abilities/details/#/User%20Specific%20Abilities/put_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users__userId__abilities_update).

Comment: when you state only the documented abilities will be accepted, are you referring to the five abilities listed within the example section of the URL you provided? Only those five abilities can be changed?

Comment: Yes - only those can be updated via the API.

More could always be added in the future.